Datastore supporting TTL with range queries
We have a data access pattern in which we need to get users added in the time range say timestamp-1 to timestamp-2 and we don't want to keep older data say max 1 day, so DB should have an inbuilt support for TTL.
Daily data could grow around 96 * 10^6 records of {user_id(varint), state_of_user(str), inserted_at(date_time)}.
Which data-store could support these:

TTL in built
Time range queries with no performance drop.


Should we opt for columnar data-store to serve this use-case ?

